# Share Ruby Programs between Linux users

Tags: user-management, ruby, installation, bundler

Our Linux (Mint) system has 2 admin users - mint & admin.  What do we need to do for admin & mint to be able to share gems?

Mint has chef, berkshelf & knife-ec2 installed via bundler in the `/home/mint/rbenv/` directory.  When switching to admin, these programs are not found:

> The program 'knife' is currently not installed. To run 'knife' please
>   ask your administrator to install the package 'chef'

How can both users share the installed packages / programs?

Comment: If they have file system access, it should just be exporting the right $GEM_HOME, $GEM_PATH, right?

Comment: For starters, you could try installing the program in another location that the user's home folder.

Comment: [Should rbenv be installed system wide or at a user level?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815750/should-rbenv-be-installed-system-wide-or-at-a-user-level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AWippler stated in his comment, install rbenv in a location other than the user's home directory.  Install in the /var/opt/rbenv directory.

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git /var/opt/rbenv
```

It is important to all adjust user permissions.  There are a variety of ways to accomplish this.  I add the users to a group called devops.

```
sudo groupadd devops
sudo usermod -a -G devops username
sudo chgrp -R devops /var/opt/rbenv/
sudo chmod 0775 /var/opt/rbenv
sudo chmod g+s -R /var/opt/rbenv/
```

Next the $RBENV_PATH needs to be shared as well.  Create a rbenv.sh script inside /etc/profile.d.

```
echo 'export RBENV_ROOT=/var/opt/rbenv' | sudo tee -a '/etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh'
echo 'export PATH=$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH' | sudo tee -a '/etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh'
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' | sudo tee -a '/etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh'
sudo chgrp devops /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
sudo chmod 0660 /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
```

Finally, install rbenv and the version that you prefer.

```
cd /tmp
sudo git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git
sudo ./ruby-build/install.sh
rbenv install ruby-version
rbenv shell ruby-version
rbenv global ruby-version
rbenv rehash
```

Note:  When installing gems via bundler, be sure to use `bundle install --system` to share with all users.